# Estimating a VAR model via OLS

Tags: multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, least-squares, bias, vector-autoregression

I am looking at Vilasuso (2001), who says that when using least-squares to estimate causality in mean, there is significant size distortion if the conditional variances are correlated.

My question is, if I estimate a VAR line by line, how can the error in equation (2) impact the estimation of equation (1).

To elaborate following the comments:

If I have a bivariate VAR(1),

[image]

Let's say the conditional variances are correlated, and I ignore it and go ahead and estimate equation (1) the top line of the VAR using OLS, how can the relationship between the conditional variances show up.

My question is, account for the relationship would I have to jointly estimate the VAR using GLS or is the OLS still possible.

I am trying to show size distortion rather than correctly estimating a model.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you find this surprising?  It is a VAR.  Equation (1) includes lagged values of the dependent variable in equation (2) on the right-hand side.  Maybe you are mixing up meanings of "error in equation (2)"?  It's not that equation 2 was estimated incorrectly that is the problem for estimating equation 1, it is the relationship between the true "error" (innovation) terms.

Comment: Hi @MattP, I am saying if the conditional covariances are correlated, but I only estimate the first equation how does the second innovation impact the estimation of the first equation!

Comment: Hi: you need to make an assumption about the covariance elements if you want to estimate a VAR with correlated error terms. The assumption usually makes certain elements zero and is often arbitrary which is a criticism of VARS. See Enders or Hamilton or Lutkepohl for detailed discussions of this issue.

Comment: I am following Vilasuso (2001) and he ignores the heteroskedasticity and then estimates the VAR using LEast Squares. My question is if the conditional variances are correlated can I estimate the VAR line by line and then the correlated conditional variances still impact the first equation (top half) of the VAR.

Comment: Hi Jack: It's been a while since I dealt with VARS but your question has to do with the difference between a reduced form VAR and a recursive VAR. It's been so long that, at the moment,  I couldn't explain it if I wanted to.  But the idea between the difference is explained in this document. ( near the end, he uses a recursive VAR by ordering the error terms ). Still, I highly recommend Enders for a more detailed and not mathematically complex explanation. Lutkepohl and Hamilton are also good but they are at a  higher level than Enders.  All the best.

Comment: Oops: I forget to include the link. http://web.uconn.edu/cunningham/econ397/VARs-SW.pdf

Comment: Jack:  I  think this one is better than the previous in terms of providing a full overview. Don't look at the other one until you check this one out first. https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ584/stck_watson_var.pdf

Answer (score -1):

You can use OLS! Remember that VAR have structural qualities that permit OLS for estimation equation by equation. Namely, in VAR models each dependent variable is a linear function of both lagged values of itself as well as the other time series included in the model. If you expand your equations by multiplying out the matrices, you will see how the errors affect the other estimates.

With reference to your question about "distortion" do you mean bias or inefficiency in the parameter estimates? I think I know how to answer your question but I want to make sure I understand it first. LMK!